# display formatted database contents on view page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Book.description with the following stored in the database:

```
    aaa

    bbb

    test

    fsdfdsfs fds fd sf sdf ds
```

I need to display the above including the line breaks in my view page.

I tried `<%= @book.description.gsub(/\n/, '<br />')%>` but I am getting the following error message :

```
private method `gsub' called for #<Hash:0xb662aa50>
```

I also tried `<%= @book.description.html_safe%>` but am getting the error message below:

```
undefined method `html_safe' for #<Hash:0xb66625f4>
```

Any suggestion ragarding this issue is most appreciated.

Comment: Could you include the `@book.description.to_s` to the question, to inspect its real content?

Comment: It's a Hash, not a string, to methods like `gsub` and `html_safe` obviously will not work on it. If the hash values are the strings you showed, you'll have to collect them first and then joining them with a BR tag will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= simple_format(@book.description) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but using simple_format displays everything on one line. I want to display the database contents like it is stored in the table column including the line breaks

Comment: Simple format does that.  There must be something else going on.